# how to enqueue javascript to manipulate acf input field in admin?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have an acf field 'select' that i want to remove some options from using js

but i can not acces the field it returns undefined

```
<select id="acf-block_5f35006ff2da4-field_5f3cce8a89941" 
class="" 
name="acf-block_5f35006ff2da4[field_5f3cce8a89941]" 
data-ui="0" data-ajax="0" 
data-multiple="0" 
data-placeholder="Select" 
data-allow_null="0">
<option value="transparent">Transparent/bakgrundsfärg</option>
</select>
```

I have tried with

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     
     console.log("loaded") //Prints out: loaded


      var element = document.getElementById("acf-block_5f35006ff2da4-field_5f3cce8a89941");
      console.log(element)// Prints out: undefined


}),
```

It seams that the block is not finished loading when DOMContentLoaded is triggerd

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function ($hook) {



    $file = sprintf("%s/js/wp-admin_blocks.js", get_template_directory());

    if(file_exists($file)) {

        $mtime = filemtime($file);
        wp_enqueue_script('ams-blocks', sprintf("%s/js/wp-admin_blocks.js", get_template_directory_uri()), [], $mtime, true);
    
    }


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an easier approach would be to remove the values before the input is presented in the admin? That would circumvent having to do things in JavaScript after the field is already displayed.

Take a look at `acf/prepare_field` hook:

```php
function my_acf_prepare_field( $field ) {
    unset($field['choices']['custom']);

    return $field;
}

// Apply to all fields.
// add_filter('acf/prepare_field', 'my_acf_prepare_field');

// Apply to select fields.
// add_filter('acf/prepare_field/type=select', 'my_acf_prepare_field');

// Apply to fields named "custom_select".
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=custom_select', 'my_acf_prepare_field');

// Apply to field with key "field_123abcf".
// add_filter('acf/prepare_field/key=field_123abcf', 'my_acf_prepare_field');
```

If you are set on JavaScript, you can use ACF's JavaScript hooks:

```js
acf.add_action('ready', function( $el ){
    
    // $el will be equivalent to $('body')
    
    
    // find a specific field
    var $field = $('#my-wrapper-id');
    
    
    // do something to $field
    
});
```

Documentation here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-custom-javascript-fields/

Comment: The problem is that i have acf for theme select witch is included in all blocks. Multiple blocks are used on same page, difrent blocks are supposed to have diferent options

Comment: i will check the hoocks out

Comment: Sadly this did not work, the script was fierd before the dom. the only solution is right now setTimeout wich is horible..

Comment: @StefanAvramovic What about their new JavaScript API: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/javascript-api/